# Format Kotlin code with space after function name

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to format Kotlin code using Android Studio. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
print("foobar")
```

However, I'd like to add a space after the function name, like this:

```
print ("foobar")
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find this option in the Android Studio code style settings. Would anyone be able to provide some guidance on how to achieve this?

**PS:**

If I'm using Java, I notice that there are options for "Space before Method declaration" and "Space before Method call". However, these options are not available in Kotlin...

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's not an option, or it would be  in the Spaces -> Before Parentheses section. And wow, that is ugly and unreadable, haha (just my opinion). I've never seen code formatted that way in any language before.

Comment: I have to agree with @Tenfour04 on this one, that looks ugly to me as well. However there is a way to make some similar formatting using extension infix functions. You can declare them like:
`infix fun Fragment.print(text: String) { ... }`

and you use it inside a fragment like this: `this print text` which looks like you are talking to the app. However infix function are not very lightweight so I wouldn't recommend it on any list scenario. You can read more on Extension and Infix functions on the Kotlin documentation page

Comment: @Tenfour04 If I'm using Java, I notice that there are options for "Space before Method declaration" and "Space before Method call". However, these options are not available in Kotlin...

Comment: Yes, they don't have complete parity of options for the two languages. I've noticed several differences in the options.